What is the best way for dapper to map column name which is different from the class property name
To simplify the case, let's say I have the following table definitions in Oracle:
create table customer
(
    id   number(10),
    name nvarchar2(1024),
    primary key (id)
);

create table customer_order
(
    id          number(10),
    customer_id number(10),
    name        nvarchar2(1024),
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (customer_id) references customer(id)
);

And I have the following classes for the database objects:
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public List<CustomerOrder> CustomerOrders { get; set; } = new List<CustomerOrder>();
}

public class CustomerOrder
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

Let's also say I want to get back a list of customers, with each customer object having a list of CustomerOrders, using the following SQL:
select      
    a.id customer_id, a.name customer_name, 
    b.id customer_order_id, b.name customer_order_name
from        
    customer a     
inner join      
    customer_order b on  a.id = b.customer_id
order by    
    a.id, b.id

As both tables (customer and customer_order) have the same columns ID and NAME, I need to change them to XXX_ID and XXX_NAME (where XXX = CUSTOMER or CUSTOMER_ORDER); otherwise, Oracle will change them to ID_1, NAME_1, etc. (if there are duplicate column names in the result).
Also, both C# classes (Customer and CustomerOrder) have the same properties ID and Name as well.
We want the database and C# class definition to be clean and not wordy (the ID in Customer is a customer ID and there is no need to explicitly say it).
As Dapper maps database columns to C# properties by either constructor parameter name or property name, how this can be mapped by Dapper automatically or what is the best way to do this in Dapper?
Even I can change the column name in the SQL query level (ID to CUSTOMER_ID, etc.), the C# class property name cannot be changed like that. I tried to use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute with both the upper (Oracle should return upper case, but tried both anyway) and lower case column name ([Column(name: "CUSTOMER_ID")], [Column(name: "customer_id")]), etc.).
It looks like that Dapper does not support
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute

Any help is highly appreciated.

Dapper has only edge support for this; however, Dapper.AOT (https://aot.dapperlib.dev/ - AOT extensions for Dapper by the same developer, with lots more configuration support) allows this option via either [DbValue(Name=...)] (Dapper.AOT's own attribute) orr [Column(...)] (the system attribute you already found).
